# Does class model a concept? (concept-to-trait, or vice versa)

Tags: c++, traits, c++-concepts

Apparently I'm missing something obvious, most likely with SFINAE - but for the life of me I just can't find what "it" is. <sub>I *could* blame my wisdom tooth, but it would sound weird because it's about wisdom...</sub>

In C++ when using Concepts (Boost, Lite or whatever) one uses something like `REQUIRES(list_of_concepts)` to enforce that eg.: a type in a function invocation follows a concept  like "`BidirectionalIteratorAccess`". But what is the corresponding "query" component for this feature? Essentially, how do I *ask* if a class type T models `BidirectionalIteratorAccess`?

All I know is that I'm not looking for `REQUIRES` or `BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT` as they are true-or-compilation-error; I'm looking for something that is true-or-false, like the `type_traits`. The documentation of Boost.Concept Assert and others suggest that one would use a SFINAE check with something like `not_satisfied<Concept>` but if so I for some reason can't figure out which part goes where. I can only guess that a SFINAE test would end up like this:

```
template <typename T> struct models_MyConcept {
    template <typename C>
    static yes_t test (some_sort_of_argument_using_MyConcept);
    template <typename C>
    static no_t test (...);
    static const bool value = sizeof(something_calling_test_with_a_C_argument_somehow) == sizeof(yes_t);
};
```

<sub>…What kind of idiot named them *wisdom* teeth anyway? And why was I digressing?</sub>

Comment: Something to do with the fact that they come through at an age where you're considered if not wise then at least adult.

Answer (score 0):

In Concepts Lite a constraint is a `constexpr bool` template function that returns true if and only if the template parameter(s) model the concept. So `BidirectionalIteratorAccess<T>()` would evaluate to `true` if and only `T` models `BidirectionalIteratorAccess`.

I understand this answer is likely not useful to you, but you did say "Boost, Lite, or whatever."